# what does intializing rosdep mean in simple terms?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

why is rosdep important and what does its initialization mean during ROS installation ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252703/what-does-intializing-rosdep-mean-in-simple-terms-?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> why is rosdep important

Please see if #q215059 can clarify that.

> what does its initialization mean during ROS installation ?

It is the step at which `rosdep` downloads a set of (yaml) files that together provide it all the information it needs to function properly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2